# How can i pass a JSX Element as Prop in React with Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to pass an Icon as a Prop to my TextInput Component like this:

```js
export interface TextInputProps {
  leadingIcon?: (props: React.ComponentProps<'svg'>) => JSX.Element
}

export const TextInputField = forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, InputFieldProps>({ leadingIcon, ...props }, ref) => {
   const LeadingIcon = leadingIcon
   return (
     <div className="flex">
        {leadingIcon ? (
           <div className="absolute inset-y-0 left-0 pl-3 flex items-center pointer-events-one">
              <LeadingIcon className="h-5 w-5 text-gray-400" />
           </div>
        ) : null}
       <input {...input} {...props} ref={ref} className="block w-full shadow-sm" />
    </div>
   )
}
```

and i want to use it like this

```js
<TextInputField leadingIcon={MailIcon} />
```

but i always get the typescript error:

```
JSX element type 'LeadingIcon' does not have any construct or call signatures .ts(2604)
```

What do i need to change to get this working?

Comment: Could you try `leadingIcon?: React.ComponentType`.

Comment: sorry, same error: "JSX element type 'LeadingIcon' does not have any construct or call signatures."

Comment: Try then to pass it as Component `<TextInputField leadingIcon={<MailIcon />} />`.

Answer (score 0):

Try: `leadingIcon?: React.ElementType`

Comment: thanks but I have already tried that. Typescript still shows me the same error

Comment: Sorry. Your problem need to use `React.ElementType`